# Validating mongoose number field with min validator

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have one field declared like this

```
  storeCreditD: {
    storeCredit: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
      min: [0, 'credit cannot be negative']
    },
    storeDeposit: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
      min: [0, 'deposit cannot be negative']
    }
  }
```

This is me changing the model

```
  const store = await Store.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: storeId },
    { $inc: { 'storeCreditD.storeCredit': credit,
      'storeCreditD.storeDeposit': credit } },
    { new: true }
```

Now, when I try to do it with negative credit (example) 
`const credit = -60` I expected that mongoose validator will throw error, since it is trying to save both fields to negative value.

To my surprise, no error was thrown and negative value was saved.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Validator that you defined here is just a [middleware](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#update-validators-only-run-for-some-operations) which will check the conditions when you try to use `.save()` method on your schema. There are also some special validators for updates (described [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#update-validators-only-run-for-some-operations)) but unfortunately they don't support `$inc` operations as those are performed in the database (outside of mongoose).

Some sort of workaround for you might be to modify your `find()` condition to include the minimal required credit:

```
  let credit = -60;
  let minStoreCredit = Math.abs(credit);

  const store = await Store.findOneAndUpdate(
      { storeId: storeId, 'storeCreditD.storeCredit': { $gte: minStoreCredit } },
      { $inc: { 'storeCreditD.storeCredit': credit } },
      { new: true });

console.log(store);
```

In this case you'll either get `null` when credit is less than `60` or updated result.